# How do I use a custom class from host in CSharpScript?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add in runtime scripting for my game, but am having trouble with an external script being loaded by:

```
CSharpScript.RunAsync(scriptToRun, null, this);
```

when the script to run uses a class from the host program.

Example:

Host program has a class called Ship
scriptToRun has:

```
Ship badGuy = new Ship();
```

and when executing

```
CSharpScript.RunAsync(scriptToRun, null, this);
```

I get this:

```
 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Ship' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I assume I need to add a reference to the script, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("Ship()", ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(typeof(Ship).Assembly));
```

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples