# How execute/run code from string variable at runtime

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to execute code that's in a string variable to get an item from a dictionary

I have tried using CSharpCodeProvider like this:

```
var text = "IconDescription";
text = "\"" + text + "\"";
var field = "Outcome[" + text + "].Value";
field = "\"" + field + "\"";

CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler()

parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;

CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, field)
```

```
var dataTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DictionaryOutcome.Rootobject>(jsonText);

var t = new List<Outcome>();

var defaultOutcome = dataTest.Response.Outcome.KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu.Select(item => new Outcome
                {
                    DataType = item.Value.DataType,
                    Value = item.Value.Value1,
                    Field = item.Key
                }).ToList();

                defaultOutcome.ToList().ForEach(item =>
                {
                    t.Add(item);
                });
```

the field variable's value is Outcome["IconDescription"].Value, and I want to execute this code to get the value from the Outcome dictionary, using the "IconDescription" Key, and get the value.

Is this possible?

I have tried the following:

```
var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default
                    .WithReferences(typeof(Dictionary<string, Outcome>).FullName)
                    .WithImports("Outcome");
var scripts = CSharpScript.Create<object>(field, scriptOptions);

var resultsx = scripts.RunAsync(null, CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

And I am getting this error:

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Outcome' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Take a look at C# (Roslyn) [Scripting Api](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples), it is created for such cases.

Comment: I keep getting an error when using this, I have updated my code and included the error

Comment: @John Take a look at this example of what you should be passing to WithReferences(): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52328168/424129

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling to even guess what you are trying to do, but as a starter, consider what you are actually doing by trying to compile that string you are constructing.

`Outcome["SomeValue"].Value` is not even close to being valid C# code:

- it has no scope
- it has no entry point
- it imports no namespaces
- it isn't terminated with a ;
- the symbol `Outcome` is not defined

You're compiling this into an executable, so I don't see how it could have any knowledge of the list of results brought back from deserializing the JSON content, where you haven't specified where you're getting this from.

You haven't specified any evidence that explains why you need such an elaborate solution to merely extract some values from JSON, so a straightforward solution might be to use the built-in features of Newtonsoft.Json:

`dataTest[0]` selects the first element in the array, when the json object is an array;

`dataTest[0]["Outcome"]` selects the property `Outcome` of the first object, which may itself be an object

`dataTest[0]["Outcome"]["Value"]` selects the property `Value` of `Outcome`

All of the string indexes here can be known only at runtime and held in variables. I don't see why you need to do any scripting at all to do this.

Comment: Okay, i thought this scripting evaluate variables at run time in the class and execute it. Outcome in my code is a dictionary variable, and I want to get an item by using Outcome["SomeValue"].Value at runtime

Comment: @John scripting might, but you hadn't added that part at the time that I wrote this answer. This answer refers to the `CSharpCodeProvider` solution. The question still stands, *why* do you need to do this?